# set variable value in SP list

Tags: jsom

I am using variable from another method (AppPath) and trying to assign its value to title field. But this is not working. I am doing some basic mistake may be not declaring global variable( I have tried that also using google, if this is the case please provide me exact step to declare and where to declare). can someone please help. Below is my code

\

```
function createList()
 {   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('coolnew');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        alert('1');
    oListItem.set_item('Title', AppPath);
          alert('2');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

 function onQuerySucceeded() {  
    var result = oList.get_title() + ' created.';  
    alert(result);  
}  

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {  
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +   
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}
```

\

Answer (score 1):

IN YOUR CASE:
 var AppPath ;
just below the script tag. 
as we know by coding standard we will generally declare all our global constant value in a starting of any function or code.
this will resolve your problem.
when you are using "var x=1" in a function its scope is limited to function.
and when you create same out side the function its scope is global.